# Preventing satellite baselayer from auto-updating over time using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online-basemaps

I need to make a map that I can reference 10, 20 years later - so I need to make sure ArcMap does not update the satellite imagery in my map.

Evidence for the auto-updating is here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012222, which reads, "The World Imagery basemap is not collectively updated. Rather, on occasion, updates occur on the different images within the basemap, and there is no actual known cycle for this activity."

Assuming I need to fix this layer in time, where are the settings to control this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Chit chat like greetings, statements of appreciation/thanks, etc should not be included in your posts here - see [help/behavior].

Comment: It's not possible to control a third-party's reference data ten or twenty years down the line.  It isn't even possible one or two months into the future, which is what that document states.

Comment: Add your own data, not the basemap. i.e. purchase commercial imagery or obtain open access imagery such as [aerial photography](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/4921f8a1-d47e-458b-873b-2a489b1c8165/vertical-aerial-photography) or satellite.

Comment: Check the imagery/layer license first, but you can download basemap services to offline imagery with the right tools.  Probably not with ArcGIS.  But once downloaded/converted, you could then use them in ArcGIS.  The tool that I use for this is is my own software, not publicly available, but I'm sure there must be other tools out there that can do the same thing.  I think I've done it with GeoServer in the past (serving out a layer from GeoServer with a WMTS service layer as input, for example, and then caching the layer in GeoServer).